# Page translation with db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating website in 3 languages and using one table of db for page translation. I wonder which field type is the best for this reason: `varchar, tinytext, text` ...? And please explain, why you think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TEXT` is the most appropriate field:
While `VARCHAR` is limited to <strike>255</strike>  65535 characters, `TINYTEXT` might be too small depending on the lengths of your texts - but if you only use short phrases it would work, too.

However, you should consider using [gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) instead of a database.

Comment: `VARCHAR` isn't limited to 255 chars. `TEXT` field should suffice, seeing it behaves as varchar whose size is over 255 bytes. Optimization on this level is meaningless seeing that various storage engines implement their own compression or storage that doesn't conform to the actual specification of the field length. `TEXT` should be more than enough for purposes of storing translations.